# Run new process as different user in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, impersonation, runas, security-context, startprocessinfo

I'm currently using a homegrown method to run a process as a different user in Vista, and I can't escape the feeling that's it hack-ish and less than ideal (in addition to the fact that it craps out UAC, crashing my app with a security exception, and forcing me to disable UAC altogether). My process consists of two projects (so two EXE files) - an "interface" and a "launch stub" - and here's the process:

1. User has a shortcut that launches "Interface.exe notepad.exe"
2. Interface.exe has a form that asks for the credentials they'd like to use
3. Interace.exe uses ProcessStartInfo to create an instance of LaunchStub.exe (LS) as the new user
4. LS uses ProcessStartInfo (with ShellExecute set to true) to launch the requested file, and since it's already running as the requested user, so is the new process.

The reason I have a two-step process is that I want users to be able to right-click on any file the OS has a default action for (.EXE, .SQL, .MSC, etc) and launch it, and ProcessStartInfo only supports that with "UseShellExecute" enabled, but that switch prevents me from using new credentials, so I can only do one at a time.

This causes a few problems - first, the user has to already exist on the computer, meaning they have to have logged in locally before. If there's no local profile for that user, the requested app will sometimes launch, but I get registry and profile exceptions because the application expects things to exist that don't yet (like an HKCU hive in the registry, which the user doesn't have because they've never logged in).

I know I should be able to just "Elevate" the rights of my application to the user they're requesting, launch my new process, and then undo the elevation, but I'm unable to find a good code sample for that, and I'm not sure that it would allow running as a completely different user. Does this all make sense? I just can't help feel like there's a better way to do this.

---

**UPDATE:** I just tried [some Impersonation code](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2003/11/24/39479.aspx) I found online, but to no avail. When used in conjunction with ProcessStartInfo, it still seems to launch processes using my current login, not the one I've provided, even though I've activated impersonation using the provided credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that you have to create your own "shell" function using the Win32 API.

Using the CreateProcessWithLogonW API you can create new processes under different credentials and optionally load user profile information.

In the code snippet below if you replace

- username - with your username
- domain - with your domain or "vbNullString"
- password - with your password
- parameter 4 - replace 0 with 'LOGON WITH PROFILE' to load the specified users profile.

See the documentation for the [CreateProcessWithLogonW API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(VS.85).aspx) for further specifics.  Going this route you have full control and full responsibility for launching the application.

Again this is just a sample and you may have to play with it a little to get it to do what you want.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Module modShell

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure STARTUPINFO
        Public cb As Integer
        Public lpReserved As String
        Public lpDesktop As String
        Public lpTitle As String
        Public dwX As Integer
        Public dwY As Integer
        Public dwXSize As Integer
        Public dwYSize As Integer
        Public dwXCountChars As Integer
        Public dwYCountChars As Integer
        Public dwFillAttribute As Integer
        Public dwFlags As Integer
        Public wShowWindow As Short
        Public cbReserved2 As Short
        Public lpReserved2 As Integer
        Public hStdInput As Integer
        Public hStdOutput As Integer
        Public hStdError As Integer
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Public hProcess As IntPtr
        Public hThread As IntPtr
        Public dwProcessId As Integer
        Public dwThreadId As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Declare Unicode Function CreateProcessWithLogonW Lib "Advapi32" (ByVal lpUsername As String, ByVal lpDomain As String, ByVal lpPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonFlags As Int32, ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Int32, ByVal lpEnvironment As IntPtr, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, ByRef si As STARTUPINFO, ByRef pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Integer
    Public Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Integer

    Public Const LOGON_WITH_PROFILE As Int32 = &H1

    Public Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS As Int32 = &H20&

    Public Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW As Int32 = &H1
    Public Const SW_HIDE As Int16 = 0
    Public Const SW_SHOW As Int16 = 5

    Public Function Shell(ByVal strCmdLine As String, ByVal strCurrentDirectory As String) As Boolean

        Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Dim si As New STARTUPINFO

        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si)
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW

        Dim result As Integer = CreateProcessWithLogonW("username", "domain", "password", 0, vbNullString, strCmdLine, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, IntPtr.Zero, strCurrentDirectory, si, pi)

        If result <> 0 Then
            Call CloseHandle(pi.hThread)
            Call CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)
        Else
            Return False
        End If

        Return True

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see what happens. If I can do it without having to use a second EXE as a stub, I'll be happy, and even more so if it doesn't crap out when UAC is enabled (I'll deal with a prompt). I'll be bakc after I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to run runas from your app. Some examples and options [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasecurity/thread/621df60a-43a8-4d9a-a20a-dc07a111b97d/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Module:

```
Module Impersonation

#Region "API Structures"
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
      Public Structure PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Dim hProcess As System.IntPtr
        Dim hThread As System.IntPtr
        Dim dwProcessId As Integer
        Dim dwThreadId As Integer
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
     Public Structure STARTUPINFO
        Dim cb As Integer
        Dim lpReserved As System.IntPtr
        Dim lpDesktop As System.IntPtr
        Dim lpTitle As System.IntPtr
        Dim dwX As Integer
        Dim dwY As Integer
        Dim dwXSize As Integer
        Dim dwYSize As Integer
        Dim dwXCountChars As Integer
        Dim dwYCountChars As Integer
        Dim dwFillAttribute As Integer
        Dim dwFlags As Integer
        Dim wShowWindow As Short
        Dim cbReserved2 As Short
        Dim lpReserved2 As System.IntPtr
        Dim hStdInput As System.IntPtr
        Dim hStdOutput As System.IntPtr
        Dim hStdError As System.IntPtr
    End Structure
#End Region

#Region "API Constants"
    Private Const LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY As Integer = &H2
    Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS As Integer = &H20
    Private Const CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE As Integer = &H4000000
    Private Const CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE As Integer = &H10
    Private Const CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP As Integer = &H200
    Private Const LOGON_WITH_PROFILE As Integer = &H1
#End Region

#Region "API Functions"
    Private Declare Unicode Function CreateProcessWithLogon Lib "Advapi32" Alias "CreateProcessWithLogonW" _
        (ByVal lpUsername As String, _
         ByVal lpDomain As String, _
         ByVal lpPassword As String, _
         ByVal dwLogonFlags As Integer, _
         ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
         ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
         ByVal dwCreationFlags As Integer, _
         ByVal lpEnvironment As System.IntPtr, _
         ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As System.IntPtr, _
         ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
         ByRef lpProcessInfo As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Integer

    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As System.IntPtr) As Integer

#End Region

    Public Sub RunProgram(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal Domain As String, ByVal Application As String, ByVal CommandLine As String)

        Dim siStartup As STARTUPINFO
        Dim piProcess As PROCESS_INFORMATION
        Dim intReturn As Integer

        If CommandLine Is Nothing OrElse CommandLine = "" Then CommandLine = String.Empty

        siStartup.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(siStartup)
        siStartup.dwFlags = 0

        intReturn = CreateProcessWithLogon(UserName, Domain, Password, LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, Application, CommandLine, _
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS Or CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE Or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE Or CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, _
        IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, siStartup, piProcess)

        If intReturn = 0 Then
            Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
        End If

        CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess)
        CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Use Runprogram() To start your Program with user/pw y like. Programm means the .exe only, parameters ar written into "commandline"

Comment: How is this module different from the one posted earlier? I'm honestly asking - it looks pretty similar, so I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious that would make clearly superior. I haven't accepted an answer yet, but the previous code has been working for me until now.

Comment: yes its very similar, its only a second function written rounded the apifunktion CreateProcessWithLogonW API - ready_to_use with errorhandling and successfeedback ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an application with different credentials than the current running process, you can use the .Net **Process** class.

```
this.Process = new Process();

this.Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "Arguments";
this.Process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\your.exe";
this.Process.StartInfo.UserName = "UserName";
string password = "some password";

this.Process.StartInfo.Password.Clear();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    this.Process.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar(c);
}


//allow the process to raise events
this.Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.Process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
//Method for handling the exit event
this.Process.Exited += new EventHandler(ApplicationProcess_Exited);

//Set the application directory as the current working directory
Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetParent("C:\").ToString();

if (this.Process.Start())
{
    // Do something on start
}
```