# Passing string from vb.net to cmd

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I'm trying to pass a string from vb.net into a command prompt window. In the end I want to use runas and use a password that was supplied earlier when logging into the application as the password. Basically I want to run the runas command, then type the password into the window (or supply it to cmd in some way)

```vb
Public Sub runCmd(ByVal pass As String, ByVal command As String, ByVal arguments As String, ByVal permanent As Boolean)
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        pi.Verb = "runas"
        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()

    End Sub
```

This is the updated code where I get the directory error

```vb
 Public Sub runCmd(ByVal pass As String, ByVal user As String, ByVal domainName As String, ByVal command As String, ByVal arguments As String, ByVal permanent As Boolean)
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
        pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        pi.Verb = "runas"
        pi.UserName = user
        pi.Domain = domainName
        pi.Password = getSecureString(pass)
        p.StartInfo = pi
        pi.UseShellExecute = False
        p.Start()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480358/run-new-process-as-different-user-in-vb-net) ?

Comment: Yea, using createprocesswithlogonW gives me an elevation error and I am using runas as a workaround because I can't disable UAC.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to start a `Process` with elevated privilege and at the same time under a different user account. So, I modified your `runCmd` function as follows based on [Can I get UAC prompt for user from batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/352130/can-i-get-uac-prompt-for-user-from-batch-file). A script is created on the fly that contains the command to run with elevated privileges. Then that script is run under the desired user account using `Process`.

```
Public Sub runCmd(ByVal password As String, ByVal user As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal command As String, ByVal permanent As Boolean)
    ' Create script with desired command to run under elevated prompt.
    Dim persist As String = If(permanent, "/K ", "/C ")
    File.WriteAllText(
        "runCmd.js",
        $"ShA=new ActiveXObject(""Shell.Application"")" & vbCrLf &
        $"ShA.ShellExecute(""cmd.exe"",""{persist} {command}"","""",""runas"",5);")
    ' Run script as domain\user with password.
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    pi.Arguments = "runCmd.js"
    pi.FileName = "wscript.exe"
    pi.UserName = user
    pi.Domain = domain
    pi.Password = GetSecureString(password)
    p.StartInfo = pi
    pi.UseShellExecute = False
    p.Start()
End Sub
```

where the `GetSecureString()` function is defined as follows.

```
Public Function GetSecureString(ByVal str As String) As SecureString
    Dim secureString As SecureString = New SecureString
    For Each ch As Char In str
        secureString.AppendChar(ch)
    Next
    secureString.MakeReadOnly()
    Return secureString
End Function
```

For example, you can call:

```
runCmd("password", "user", "domain", "dir", True)
```

you will get the UAC prompt, a command window will open, the `dir` command will be run, and the command window will stay opened.

You could further customize your solution by looking at the different options available with [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute) and [wscript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript).

Comment: @Adam - Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: @Adam - Did not hear from you.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I tried this out and I get an error at the process.start line saying "the directory name is invalid"

Comment: @ Adam - Could you append your new code to your original question? And what were the values of the `runCmd()` arguments that you used when getting the error?

Comment: @Adam - And what were the values of the runCmd() arguments that you used when getting the error?

Comment: runCmd(strPass, strUser, "<domain>", "", "/user:" + strUser + " ""cmd""", True)

Comment: @ Adam - Upon further research I realized there was something missing in my original answer, I updated it significantly.